# Should you Unit Test your Unit Tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I am wondering whether it would be a good practice to unit tests the unit tests, otherwise, how do we know that the unit tests are without bugs?

Answer (score 0):

Unit test cases are predictable, based on code logic. Which means that you should know the expected result of this test case in advance.  All test cases are designed by users. There is no need to write unit test for unit test. If the test relies on some packages or helper functions, these test fixtures need to be fully tested.